# Move to numeric sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of tabs that are numeric (1-12), representing the month of the year. I have a dropdown that  after selecting a month it updates a cell with the corresponding month number. I need to move to these tabs after the month is selected.

The value of the month to move is set in range E13 in the Home sheet. I tried the following code to move to the corresponding tab

```
MonthTab = Sheets("Home").Range("E13")
Sheets(MonthTab).Select
```

The problem is that as MonthTab is numeric it moves the to nth sheet position rather to the sheet called MonthTab.

Any ideas how I can move to MonthTab sheet rather than to the nth position

Comment: [`Dim MonthTab As String`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30785133/4088852).

Comment: Thanks @Comintem. Simple